# How to write an annotation with members in PlantUML?

Tags: annotations, plantuml

I want to write an annotation with members in PlantUML. Specifically, I want to describe this Java code in PlantUML:

```java
public @interface Foo {
    String bar();
    String baz();
}
```

I tried to write it in PlantUML, but it causes syntax error:

```
@startuml
annotation Foo {
    String bar()
    String baz()
}
@enduml
```

[image: plantuml-syntax-error]

However, it's working when I omit the members:

```
@startuml
annotation Foo
@enduml
```

[image]

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to write annotations with members now: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuKhCoyilIIp9pCzJSClFLwZcKW22u9AYpBnqXQJ48WrDL84ge40jbqDgNWfGCm00

According to the [comment](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/458#issuecomment-792271118), it's available starting at version V1.2020.2.

Answer (score 1):

In PlantUML, annotations can not have members (hence the syntax error).

To display a UML diagram for your code, you will need to use another solution, like adding the annotation as a separate entity:

```
@startuml
annotation interface

class Foo {
    String bar();
    String baz();
}


interface -- Foo
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML Diagram of above code]

Or include the annotation in the class name definition:

```
@startuml
class "@interface Foo" as Foo {
    String bar();
    String baz();
}
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML Diagram of above code]

Comment: Thank you for confirming that PlantUML doesn't support annotations with members. I've submitted a ticket at https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/458.